# How do I convert java.util.HashSet[java.lang.Long] to Scala Set[Long]

Tags: scala

I'm using:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.Set
```

This works:

```
val a: java.util.HashSet[java.lang.Long] =  javaFunction(...)
val b: Set[java.lang.Long] = a.asScala.toSet
```

but what I want is a `Set[Long]`, not a `Set[java.lang.Long]`.  When I try this:

```
val a: java.util.HashSet[java.lang.Long] =  javaFunction(...)
val b: Set[Long] = a.asScala.toSet
```

I get: `Expression of type scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.Long] doesn't conform to expected type scala.collection.Set[Long]`.

Why is this and how do I get a `Set[Long]`?

Answer (score 6):

Simply:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val b: Set[Long] = a.asScala.map(Long2long).toSet
```